# What does "late Sep. through Oct." mean?

Tags: vocabulary

What does "late Sep. through Oct." mean?

I have encountered this sentence [here](http://www.italyguides.it/en/lazio/rome/travel-guides/rome-video-guides/rome-in-a-nutshell).

I know *through* means *from the beginning to the end of ...*. However, an example of [this source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/through#british-1-1-2), that is *She works Monday through Thursday (= from Monday to Thursday)*, implies that it can mean *until* as well. So, does "late Sep. through Oct." mean *until the end of Oct.* or *until the end of Sep*? 
I guess the first interpretation is more acceptable.

Comment: Literally, "late Sep. through Oct." means starting on some date in late Sept., and ending on Oct. 31. However in actual use, it might be an earlier date in Oct. to conform to some schedule to account for work weeks, holidays, etc. If the meaning was "until the end of Sept." there would be no need to mention "Oct.".

Comment: Also, the definitions of *through* and *until* are not the same here. *through* indicates time from start point to end point, while *until* only indicates the end point.

Comment: @user3169 Does *to* mean the same as *until* or *through* in *from Monday to Thursday*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Though* in this context means *until the end of.*

A time period lasting *through October* finishes at the end of October.

A time period lasting *through Thursday* finishes at the end of Thursday.

A time period *Monday to Thursday* usually means the same thing, but *through* is more precise in that it specifies *to the end of Thursday.*

The context will normally make clear whether this means the end of the business day (school day, etc.) or the end of the entire day (ending at 12:00am Friday morning).

Comment: How will we say *someone works from the start of Mon. until the start of Thu.*, in other words *from Mon. through Wed.*?